# code smell when pulling from cache with multiple default values?

Tags: java, caching

We have a table with 4 columns:

```
A B C VALUE  
1 2 0 100  
0 3 3 200  
0 0 7 400  
0 0 0 700
```

The key consists of 3 columns: A, B and C.
We save this table on a `HashMap<ImmutableTriple<Integer, Integer, Integer>, Integer>` object.

Zero represents the default value, so where no exact key is found, we should pull the relevant key according to the logic below:

```
value = cache.get(new ImmutableTriple<>(a, b, c));
if (value != null) {
    return value;
}
value = cache.get(new ImmutableTriple<>(a, b, 0));
if (value != null) {
    return value;
}
value = cache.get(new ImmutableTriple<>(a, 0, c));
if (value != null) {
    return value;
}
value = cache.get(new ImmutableTriple<>(a, 0, 0));
if (value != null) {
    return value;
}
value = cache.get(new ImmutableTriple<>(0, 0, 0));
if (value != null) {
    return value;
}
```

The problem that getting by key of 3 IDs with default values produce a code smell. Are there any better\cleaner ways of doing this?

Comment: Wouldn’t it be better to create a custom class for the triple identifier and encompass the matching logic in the `equals` method?

Comment: @JoakimDanielson but if same code is still there, just overrides the equals method, does it make it better? i mean, the code smell is still there , just in other place, right?

Comment: You don’t have to create 5 objects, only one since all the matching logic is inside the `equals` method so for me it would be an improvement

Answer (score 0):

You can create a "mask map" for all possible states of triplets with default value e.g.:

```
private static List<Integer[]> mask = new ArrayList<>();
static {
    mask.add(new Integer[] {null, null, null});
    mask.add(new Integer[] {0, null, null});
    mask.add(new Integer[] {null, 0, null});
    mask.add(new Integer[] {null, null, 0});
    mask.add(new Integer[] {null, 0, 0});
    mask.add(new Integer[] {0, null, 0});
    mask.add(new Integer[] {0, 0, null});
    mask.add(new Integer[] {0, 0, 0});
}
```

Let say null, means key value must be filled. Then you can create list of triplets keys from this mask:

```
List<Triple<Integer, Integer, Integer>> triples = mask.stream()
                                                          .map(row -> genrateTriple(row, a, b, c))
                                                          .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

The code for generateTriplets:

```
 private Triple<Integer, Integer, Integer> genrateTriple(Integer[] row, int... values) {
    int[] tripleElems = new int[3];
    for (int i = 0; i < row.length; i++) {
        tripleElems[i] = row[i] == null ? values[i] : row[i];
    }
    return new ImmutableTriple<>(tripleElems[0], tripleElems[1], tripleElems[2]);
}
```

and use it in search:

```
return triples.stream()
           .map(triple -> cache.get(triple))
           .findFirst()
           .orElse(null);
```

But I'm not sure if this is better than your "code smell" ;).

EDITED:
Of course this will be more efficent if you avoid creating intermediate collection (findFirst is a short circut operator):

```
Integer result = mask.stream()
        .map(row -> genrateTriple(row, a, b, c))
        .map(cache::get)
        .findFirst()
        .orElse(null);
```

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes having an exploded loop isn't necessarily a bad thing, if it makes the code more readable.

I would recommend you keep your code as it, because as you will see in a moment, if you try to compact it you could very well end up with something worse. If you insist, continue reading.

---

My idea is simple: you are essentially trying to loop through several masks to use for your match pattern. The mask in this case is "whether to use id or default".

1. Mask nothing, if no match,
2. Mask c, if no match,
3. Mask b, if no match,
4. Mask b c, if no match,
5. Mask a b c, if no match,
6. Return null.

Hence we can use some kind of data structure to store the mask, something like this:

```
    // true = use id (don't mask); false = use default (mask).
    List<ImmutableTriple<Boolean, Boolean, Boolean>> matchMasks = new ArrayList<>();
    matchMasks.add(new ImmutableTriple<>(true, true, true));
    matchMasks.add(new ImmutableTriple<>(true, true, false));
    matchMasks.add(new ImmutableTriple<>(true, false, true));
    matchMasks.add(new ImmutableTriple<>(true, false, false));
    matchMasks.add(new ImmutableTriple<>(false, false, false));
```

Of course, you can use `List` of `List`, `Array` of `Array`, or anything sensible to store this mask.

Now we can use a loop to compact your code:

```
private Integer match(int a, int b, int c)
{
    Integer value = null;
    // Loop through match rules.
    for (ImmutableTriple<Boolean, Boolean, Boolean> mask : matchMasks)
    {
        // Check whether to apply mask.
        int aId = mask.getLeft() ? a : 0;
        int bId = mask.getMiddle() ? b : 0;
        int cId = mask.getRight() ? c : 0;
        // Try to match cache.
        value = cache.get(new ImmutableTriple<>(aId, bId, cId));
        // Stop if match found.
        if (value != null) break;
    }
    return value;
}
```

All put together into one class:

```
public class Test
{
    private HashMap<ImmutableTriple<Integer, Integer, Integer>, Integer> cache = <your table here>;
    private List<ImmutableTriple<Boolean, Boolean, Boolean>> matchMasks = new ArrayList<>();

    public Test()
    {
        // true = use id (don't mask); false = use default (mask).
        this.matchMasks.add(new ImmutableTriple<>(true, true, true));
        this.matchMasks.add(new ImmutableTriple<>(true, true, false));
        this.matchMasks.add(new ImmutableTriple<>(true, false, true));
        this.matchMasks.add(new ImmutableTriple<>(true, false, false));
        this.matchMasks.add(new ImmutableTriple<>(false, false, false));
    }

    private Integer match(int a, int b, int c)
    {
        Integer value = null;
        // Loop through match rules.
        for (ImmutableTriple<Boolean, Boolean, Boolean> mask : this.matchMasks)
        {
            // Check whether to apply mask.
            int aId = mask.getLeft() ? a : 0;
            int bId = mask.getMiddle() ? b : 0;
            int cId = mask.getRight() ? c : 0;
            // Try to match cache.
            value = this.cache.get(new ImmutableTriple<>(aId, bId, cId));
            // Stop if match found.
            if (value != null) break;
        }
        return value;
    }
}
```

P.S. For this specific case, since 0 = default you can use 1 and 0 instead of true and false for your mask and do this `int aId = mask.getLeft() * a;`, but this is trivial.

As you can see, although we did "compact" your code into a loop, its effect is very debatable. In fact, I would argue that this code is actually less readable. Hence again, sometimes it's not necessarily bad to stick with an exploded loop.